# Copy one static cell's value onto a second dynamic cell (with specific row criteria) based on a third cell's value

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula

I have a VBA script that starts by looking at `'YTDInfo'!$J$2` for a name.  Then it searches, from the beginning of the workbook, for a matching sheet name against the entry in `'YTDInfo'!$J$2`.  If the name is found then it looks at that sheet's "amount paid" cell and brings that value onto `'YTDInfo'!$M$2`.

The script moves onto the next matching sheet and so on, for over 100 sheets, adding all of the payments made to that one person.  It places the total summed value in cell `'YTDInfo'!$M$2`.

I have a list of just over 100 names and I would like to automate a component of this process.

I already have:

`'YTDInfo'!A2` ~ `'YTDInfo'!A100`+ populated with all of the sheet names.

`'YTDInfo'!B2` with the Marlett font and I am using "a" (for a check mark).

When `'YTDInfo'!B2`="a" (or B3 or B4... ="a") `'YTDInfo'!$J$2` populates with the next name on the list (name comes from A3, A4 or A5 - respectively).

`$J$2` has an array CSE formula.  When `'YTDInfo'!$J$2` populates with the name I run the script and it builds up the total and puts it in `'YTDInfo'!$M$2`.

I like this manual because I can track which name has the YTD info and I can follow any duplicates, or spelling mistakes, in the sheets.

Here's the other manual part that I'd like to now automate...
When `'YTDInfo'!$M$2` populates I need to place the value into the `'YTDInfo'!Fn` (n for row number) cell, but in the specific row that corresponds to where the name came from.

**For example...**

This is all done on the YTDInfo sheet, so I don't keep cluttering the text with that piece of info. ...and `$J$2` and `$M$2` are static cells being the only ones read and populated by the script.

If `B11` is manually checked (`B11`="a"), the `A12`'s name will pass onto `J2`.  That name can be John.  When I run the script all of the sheet names that have John and his amounts paid (`'john 10-17-2017'!AB17` + `'john 10-21-2017'!AB17` + so on and so on) will add up and show in `M2`.

Let's say it all equals... $12,000.  How do I then tell Excel that the value from `M2` ($12,000) can now be copied into John's YTD cell (onto `F12`) without having to copy and special paste values manually?

Thank you so much for any help.  I know simple Excel stuff, but I can't figure out these pieces.  I am very willing to use formulas or VBA - without any fears, yikes!  I'm happy to donate a bit for your time and to be able to learn something from you.

```
Sub YTDTotal_Click() ' 

    Keyboard Shortcut: Ctrl+h 

    Dim mysheet As Worksheet ' 
    Sheets("YTDInfo").Select ' 
    Cells.Clear 

    For Each mysheet In Worksheets 

         mysheet.Select 

         If Left(mysheet.Name, Range("YTDInfo!K2")) = Range("YTDInfo!J2") Then 
             ActiveSheet.Range("H22").Select Selection.Copy 
             Sheets("YTDInfo").Select 
             Range("M2").Select Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteAll, Operation:=xlAdd, SkipBlanks:= _ False, Transpose:=False 
         End If 

    Next mysheet 

    Sheets("YTDInfo").Select ' 
    ActiveSheet.Range("H22").Select 

    End Sub
```

Comment: Better get this in quick before the flurry from the rest of the community... Can you please provide the script that you have already so that we can point out the areas in your code that we believe could be changed to achieve this?

Comment: Here's what my script now '
'Sub YTDTotal_Click()

' Keyboard Shortcut: Ctrl+h
'

Dim mysheet As Worksheet

' Sheets("YTDInfo").Select
' Cells.Clear


For Each mysheet In Worksheets
mysheet.Select

If Left(mysheet.Name, Range("YTDInfo!K2")) = Range("YTDInfo!J2") Then
ActiveSheet.Range("H22").Select
Selection.Copy
Sheets("YTDInfo").Select
    Range("M2").Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteAll, Operation:=xlAdd, SkipBlanks:= _
        False, Transpose:=False


End If

Next mysheet
Sheets("YTDInfo").Select
' ActiveSheet.Range("H22").Select


End Sub

Comment: On a single and manual search it works great, but the end just leaves me with the value in the M2 cell.  I would like this value to be moved or copied into the row where the request originated.  If I searched for the name that started in A42 then I would like for the YTD total to end up in F42 and not only in M2.

Comment: Just had another thought... how about a "vlookup" in VBA that would match J2's value to column A and if it's a match then write M2 to Fn

Comment: I just added this and it worked... now how do I get this to lookup A and add M2 to F?  sheet_name = "becerra"
Sal = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(sheet_name, Sheet1.Range("J:M"), 4, False)
MsgBox "Salary is : $ " & Sal

Comment: 1) An image of your data, particularly the layout of the names and where you want the sums to go would really help     2)  Don't select each sheet! Check if the sheet.Name contains the substring <Name of person>, if yes, then use With statement to retrieve the required cell value. Store this value in a variable and add to it as you loop then write back to sheet at the end  3) Any reason why J2 cannot be populated using data validation ? Would allow you to chose names from a drop down list   4) How is location of sheet's "amount paid" cell determined? Same cell ref in each sheet?

Comment: Thanks for your offer to help, QHarr. I found an answer by just working through it.

Answer (score 0):

I got it.  I searched and tried and cried and I DAMN GOT IT!! Thanks for the input, you guys.  I hope this helps somebody with a similar setup or requirement.  There are also probably much cleaner ways to accomplish this task, but I'm not an expert.  ...and I once heard that if the code works and doesn't generate errors then it's not really wrong.  It may take a little longer, but if it works... then... :o).

```
Sub YTDTotal_Click()
'
'
'
beginScript:
    If Sheets("YTDInfo").Range("J2") = 0 Then
        MsgBox "No More Names To Look Up"
        GoTo LastLine
    Else


Dim mysheet As Worksheet
Dim sheet_name As String

ActiveSheet.Range("M2").Clear

For Each mysheet In Worksheets
mysheet.Select

If Left(mysheet.Name, Range("YTDInfo!K2")) = Range("YTDInfo!J2") Then
ActiveSheet.Range("H22").Select
Selection.Copy
Sheets("YTDInfo").Select
Range("M2").Select
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteAll, Operation:=xlAdd, SkipBlanks:= _
    False, Transpose:=False

End If

Next mysheet
Sheets("YTDInfo").Select
sheet_name = ActiveSheet.Range("J2")
Z = 200
Do
x = x + 1: y = y + 0
If Range("A" & x) = sheet_name Then Range("F" & x) = Range("M2"): Range("B" & x) = "a"

If x = Z Then Exit Do
' Use "Exit Do" for continuous operation
' Use "Exit Sub" for a one time check
Loop
x = 0: y = 0
End If

GoTo beginScript

LastLine:

End Sub
```